# PHP - Passing variables to index.php

Tags: php, oop

It is the index.php file in root directory:

**index.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'engine.php';
require_once 'startController.php';

$engine = new Engine('start');

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>

        </title>
    </head>
</html>
```

In engine class there is another object

**engine.php**

```
class Engine
{
    puublic $controller = null;

    public function __construct($controller)
    {
        $controllerFile = $controller.'Controller';
        $this->controller = new $controllerFile('Page');
    }
}
```

and controller class

**startController.php**

```
class startController
{
    public function __construct($text)
    {
        $variable = 'Start'.$text; // output "StartPage" because of $text val.
    }
}
```

Question is: how to pass`$variable` from `startController` object to **index.php**, and display betwen `title` markups?

Comment: Set `$variable` to a class property, add a getter method that returns that property (if property isn't public) then call that method on an instance of the startController class. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified:

```
<?php

$vars = array('title' => '');

function foo(&$vars) {
    $vars['title'] = 'Bar';
}

foo($vars);
?>
<html>
<title><?php echo $vars['title']; ?></title>
...
```

You could use $vars as a global:

```
<?php

$vars = array('title' => '');

function foo() {
    global $vars;
    $vars['title'] = 'Bar';
}

foo();
```

But perhaps you are better off using a view object accessible to your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following method:

```
<?php
class startController
{
    public $variable;
    public function __construct($text){
        $this->variable = 'Start'.$text; // output "StartPage" because of $text val.
    }

}

?>
```

And

```
<?php
class Engine
{
    public $controller = null;
    public $variable;

    public function __construct($controller)
    {
        $controllerFile = $controller.'Controller';
        $this->controller = new $controllerFile('Page');
    $this->variable = $this->controller->variable;
    }
}
?>
```

And in index.php

```
<?php

require_once 'engine.php';
require_once 'startController.php';

$engine = new Engine('start');
echo $engine->variable;
?>
```

Hope this help you :)